# How to get permission to create full-text index?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

I tried to create a full-text index on my new full-text catalog and got this error:

```
Msg 9967, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A default full-text catalog does not exist in database 'foo' or user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

FYI--

- I connected to the target sql server with Windows Authentication
- Full-text indexing appears installed (right-clicking the table, I see the `Full-text Index ->` option)
- I verified that my full-text catalog was created
- This is my first time setting up a full-text catalog and index

What do I need to do in Sql Server 2005 and/or in Windows Server 2003 to get permissions?

Please be thorough (assume I am a sysadmin n00b). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the database-owner permission, that's all you need to do there.

Full-text indexing is an **option** in the SQL Server installer.  You may need to go back and add the feature.

Other than that, these instructions should take care of you:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/FTS_-_How_to_use_TSQL_to_Create_Full-Text_Indexes

Comment: Thanks @Miles. Your link showed me my fault. The error was with the "default catalog" part--not the permissions.  Once I added `ON MyCatalog` to the SQL statement, it worked.